# HTML5 canvas, user drawing resize and rotate

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas on which the user can draw with some sort of pen.
The canvas height is slightly larger than the width. The actual size depends on several variables.
I want to give the user the ability to rotate his/her drawing.
I'm creating a new canvas on which i draw the old canvas rotated.

Below is how i did 180 degrease.

```
if(rotation==180){
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2);
    ctx.drawImage(drawing,0,0);
}
```

Now for the 90 degrease I also have to do a resize because otherwise it won´t fit anymore.
I'm not even sure where to start. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7243407/532102

Comment: You want to rotate the canvas or the drawing? The way I understand, it seems you're only allowing your user to rotate the whole image (i.e. the canvas) by multiples of 90, like you would rotate in MS Paint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this posts

[HTML5 canvas image rotate left rotate right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912818/html5-canvas-image-rotate-left-rotate-right)

http://phptechworld.blogspot.in/2012/10/html5-canvas-image-rotation.html

Answer (score 0):

u can use CSS3 for rotation:like

```
h1
{
rotation-point:50% 50%;
rotation:180deg;
}
```

Comment: It is my intention to be able to 'store' the result. Therefor CSS rotation isn't going to work. Thanks though.