# Rotate and move ball image Html 5

Tags: html, css, animation

now image will be moved but not rotating. i'm implementing moving functionalities. but supporting only IE10.

This is my script,

```
var ball = new Image;
window.onload = function () {
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var w = c.width = 800;
var h = c.height = 600;
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var dx = -1, dy = 0;
var x = 400, y = 200, a = 0;
var deg2rad = Math.PI / 180;
var da = 10 * deg2rad;
var bw = ball.width;
var bh = ball.height;
setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(a);
    ctx.drawImage(ball, -bw, -bh);
    ctx.rotate(-a);
    ctx.translate(-x, -y);
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    if ((x - bw < 0) || (x + bw > w)) {
        dx *= -1; da *= -1;
    }
    if ((y - bh < 0) || (y + bh > h)) {
        dy *= -1; da *= -1;
    }
}, 30);
}
ball.src = 'images/beachball.png';
```

and, this is my Html design,

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

anybody can help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to increment your rotation variable:

```
x += dx;
y += dy;
```

should also have:

```
a += da;
```

Note though that rotating it in the way you are doing it isn't going to rotate around the center of the image; it will rotate around the corner. You will need to adjust the placement by changing the line:

```
ctx.drawImage(ball, -bw, -bh);
```

to

```
ctx.drawImage(ball, -bw/2, -bh/2);
```

Comment: This is working but the image will not rotate a same position. it will rotate up and down, up and down

Comment: hmm. [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TPNN/1/) that works (on WebKit anyway; I don't have access to IE). It uses the edits I detailed above.

Answer (score 0):

Check your rotation method... Here is link to same question that i answered earlier,

[HTML5 canvas image rotate left rotate right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912818/html5-canvas-image-rotate-left-rotate-right/12913818#12913818)